# Reactjs with Aurelia

Tags: reactjs, aurelia

I'm looking for some help with using ReactJS with Aurelia.  I went to http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/03/how-to-use-react-js-in-aurelia/ page, which seems to be the only page on google that talks about it but his method did not work for me.  I am trying to full understand how to integrate the two.  If anyone has done this already or has a working example that I can try to figure out that would be amazing.  Any help at this point is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would contact the author and explain what isn't working and why, he would probably be interested in knowing that it isn't working.

Comment: Hi Seroth, author here. I will gladly modify the article to accommodate your needs. Would a fully working example as you mentioned be helpful? If so, I can create a Github repository with working code and demo example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see some example code [here](https://github.com/Vheissu/aurelia-react-example) on Github. You can also view a live demo [here](http://vheissu.github.io/aurelia-react-example/) (using the code in the linked repository). More strategies for using React with Aurelia will be added over time. For now, things are basic, but the code explains more than the aforementioned blog post (which will also be updated).

Comment: I was able to add a React component based on the updated documentation.  Thank you so much.  I would also ask if you can update the docs to the jspm install jsx plugin as I had to check npm for the proper procedure.  I am coming into React and Aurelia as a complete novice at both so the docs set from a complete novice point of view really helps.  More info is always better.  Once I get everything operating nicely I will probably put together a huge blog on my experience.  I will def reference ppl to your doc.  Thanks a bunch.  Time to get cracking on augmenting the code for my needs.

Comment: Question, How would I load more than one component using the same jsx file?

Comment: You would just define another component and export it. You can have multiple components being exported.

Comment: Hi,the same example i followed,works fine and  here i have a click function in my view(react) **onClick={this.myfun}** while clicking it needs to take it to aurelia where the **myfun** is. any idea

Comment: Has anyone done this with typescript Aurelia and tsx files using webpack?